# How can I create a live steam using gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, gst-launch

I would like to stream my webcam, I tried with vlc, but I'm getting a 10-15s delay between the server and client on the same network

```
vlc v4l2:// :v4l2-dev=/dev/video0 :v4l2-width=640 :v4l2-height=480 --sout="#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/live.ts}" -I dummy
```

Now I would like to test gstreamer, but I couldn't found any example, how can I setup a live webcam stream(rtsp or http) using gstreamer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the rtsp-server examples in
[http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-rtsp-server/tree/examples](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-rtsp-server/tree/examples%20gst-rtsp-server)

Comment: The link is dead.  Perhaps the follwoing Gstreamer  repo can be used https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 4):

To create a YouTube live event, one needs a RTMP stream containing x264+aac.

```
gst-launch -v videotestsrc \
    ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 \
    ! x264enc key-int-max=60 \
    ! h264parse \
    ! flvmux name=mux \
    audiotestsrc ! queue ! audioconvert ! ffenc_aac ! aacparse ! mux. \
    mux. ! rtmpsink location="rtmp://<stream-server-url>/"
```

Key frames in live feed must appear each 2 seconds at most, thus `key-int-max=<double framerate>`.

Note that RTMP works over TCP, so on a bad channel it will suffer significant delays.

Comment: what will be play URL of this. I am using nginx rtmp server. that requires one stream key. where is that key?

Comment: @Ashish this is a question about nginx plugin. I suggest that you look up nginx-rtmp manuals/howtos.